# I can't use private or public or neither for this

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im working on a game in unity to kickstart my game development, and I ran into this problem.

```cs
void OnCollisionExit(Collision other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.layer == 0 && _isGrounded) 
    {
        _isGrounded = false;
    }
}

void Update() 
{
    //regular ol basic walk
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        rigidBody.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.left * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        //S P E E D
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
        {
            rigidBody.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.left * runSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
```

Errors:

> error CS0136: A local or parameter named 'other' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter

Now with `private` before void:

> error CS0106: The modifier 'private' is not valid for this item

The same thing happens if I try with `public`; except then it replaces all instances of `private` with `public`.

Comment: could you please provide us with the code surrounding this? because i am _pretty_ certain the error is not in the code you provided.

Comment: "A local or parameter" So this code is inside another method body? Are you missing a close brace before this code?

Comment: Please add all relevant code to your question. Currently there is no issue in the code you provide ... Accept maybe your `Update`issing some closing `}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `other` variable name twice in the code, one is argument to `OnCollisionExit()` function and another in at class level. I am saying class level as it is not defined anywhere in the code which you posted with this question.

To solve this issue, instead of adding access modifier change name of parameter to something else,

example,

```
void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision){
                            //^^^^^^^^^^ Here is the change
     if (collision.gameObject.layer == 0 && _isGrounded) {
           _isGrounded = false;
        }
  }
```

Comment: Anyway the name `other` makes only sense for `OnTriggerEnter` where the parameter is `Collider other`. Here it could simply be `Collision collision` since it holds all kind of information about the collision itself, not only a reference to the other collider ;)

Comment: @derHugo, thanks for your suggestion, I updated my code to use proper name